# Complex integral $\int_{|z|=2} \operatorname{Re}(z)dz$ problem with limit

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I had a problem on my exam.
We had an integral like $$ \int_C \frac{z+1}{(z-1)^2(z+3)} + \int_C \operatorname{Re}(z) dz $$ where $C=O^+(0,2)=\{|z|=2\}$. I calculated the first integral using residue method and I don’t know what to do with second one. I saw that I should make it an integral of $$z + \overline{z}$$ but I Don’t understanding how limits work in this integrated

Comment: Hello, as you can tell we are not here to do your homework, thus you should add some personal tries, why I did not work, a hint: multiply by two, Re is linear

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Use `\overline`, not `\lineabove`

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out an answer. $$\int_{|z|=2} Rez dz=\int_{|z|=2} 0.5(z+ \overline{z})dz= \int_{|z|=2} 0.5(z+ \frac{4}{z}) dz = \int_{\vert z \vert = 2} \frac{z}{2}dz  + \int_{\vert z \vert =2} \frac{2}{z} dz$$
We have
$$\int_C \frac{z}{2} dz= 0$$ This is because this function has no residue in the circle circle centered at $0$ of radius $2$.

The second integral $$\int_C \frac{2}{z} dz = 2\pi i * \text{res} f(z)= 2 \pi i *2= 4\pi i$$
This resf(z) is calculated as $\text{res}(f,z_0) = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} [(z-z_0) * 2/z] = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} 2 = 2.$

Comment: You solved it with help from a little bird, maybe? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Render $\Re(z)=(z+\overline{z})/2.$ Then along the integration path you also have $z\overline{z}=|z|^2=4$. Thus

$\Re(z)=\frac12(z+4/z).$

And I am done here. You should he able to do the integration when you have a function of $z$ alone with only isolated singularities.